# Netbeans, Control-O to open class finds the class but not the file

Tags: java, netbeans

In a Netbeans, working on a Java project, one can use control-o and type few letters of a Java class to quickly see a list of class matching the input. Focusing on it by moving arrows or double clicking typically opens the file containing that class.

In Netbeans 8.0.1 there is a double entry in the search results at the top and double-clicking on the first one returns a 'file not found' error (visible in the lower left corner of Netbeans).

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect two possible reasons:

1. Netbeans cache in `~/.netbeans/8.0/var/` could be corrupt in a way. I sometimes clear it by deleting the directory and restarting Netbeans. It fixes the indexing issues.
2. The classpath to the classes showing up in the search filter is not reachable to Netbeans or has no sources.